# How can I import e-mail data from outlook into a SharePoint list?

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, outlook

I want to copy an email data into a SharePoint list. User will select which e-mail s/he wants to add and e-mail will be coppied into a multi-line text box. Also, e-mail attachments will be copied automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

First you need configure incoming email service.

[MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvagan/archive/2008/01/26/incoming-email-configuration-moss.aspx)

[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx)

Second you want to Create a folder structure for incoming email, you can create Event Handle
or workflow to do this when the email be created in list.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Compeng,

This seems like a pretty complicated task (it looks easy if you already have the prerequisites configured).  Essentially you have to enable and configure the SMTP Service in CA, enable sites to receive emails, activate the feature on the site collection/site level and then enable the individual list settings.  There are a few more things you can do with it and this video (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/Video/ff679958) has a lot of good information about setting it all up.

Let me know if that works out for you!

- Matt

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to go 3rd party, there are a couple solutions that do a pretty good job.

- [Colligo](http://www.colligo.com/products/sharepoint/colligo-email-manager/)
- [Harmon.ie](http://harmon.ie/integrate-sharepoint-outlook)